# Despite turning on SSH in imager, I am getting a port 22: connection refused on my RASPBERRY pi

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to connect to my r pi 3 from SSH, using my phone as my hotspot.
I opened up imager and put up the phone's ssid and password along with enabling ssh
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiOdW.png)
My phone(Redmi note 9 pro) doesn't display the IP address of devices connected(only mac addresses) so i connect my laptop to the hotspot and run nmap to get raspberry pi's IP address
I do get but when i use the -

```
ssh pi@<IPaddr>
```

I always get a  -

```
ssh: connect to host <ipaddr> port 22: Connection refused
```

Could it be that the ssh file is not made by imager - because no such file exists in the boot drive after the OS loads up in the sd card. I did try adding a ssh file w/o extention on the boot drive but that also didnt work.
Or is it because the hotspot is slow? I am running on 2.4GHz.
When I try the approach of connecting it to a PC's hotspot it doesn't even connect.
Can anyone address how to properly set up my raspberry pi to access it from the ssh? Is there any other approach like using an usb.
Also I am doing this on a Windows machine, I will not be able to use a monitor to access the r pi, and i also cant install Linux on my machine rn

Comment: The fact that you're getting a connection refused message might indicate that you have a firewall on the Pi thats blocking port 22. To be honest, there could be many reasons why you're not getting a connection, but hopefully it's that one, because it's easy to fix. Permit port 22 and try again.

Comment: @FreudianSlip is it possible to permit port 22 from boot folder of the sd card itself?

Comment: There's no `pi` username by default any more IIRC.